# Why is Potassium permanganate a better catalyst than Potassium Iodide?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I did an experiment measuring the activation energy of Hydrogen Peroxide with different catalysts. Potassium Permanganate seems to be a better catalyst as the activation energy was lower than the one with Potassium Iodide. However, I would like know why that was the case. Was it because of the different structures?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SE chem. Try to add some more detail to you question, are you talking about the decomposition of hydrogen peroxide to water and oxygen gas?

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the mechanism of catalysis, they both react with hydrogen peroxide as follows.

$$\ce{2KMnO4 + 3H2O2 => 3O2 + 2MnO2 + 2KOH + 2H2O}$$
$$\ce{KI + H2O2 => KIO + H2O}$$
$$\ce{KIO + H2O2 => KI + H2O + O2}$$

The most important bit is that in the first equation the peroxide is actually a reducing agent and the permanganate doesn't actually catalyze the decomposition of peroxide it just happens to react with it to produce oxygen and is not found unchanged after the reaction. Potassium iodide is a true catalyst, it reacts with the peroxide but is regenerated everytime oxygen is produced. Based on that, you can't actually compare the two as catalysts because only the iodide is one.